# will_paginate limit and order not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use will_paginate for the nested notes in the contact show view. The contacts controller looks like this:

```
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id], :include => :notes)
@notes = @contact.notes.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5, :order => "created_at ASC")
```

The contacts show view has the `<%= will_paginate @notes %>` tag. This works, but the sort order is not correct, it shows all 6 notes instead of 5 and the pagination at the top is reversed, it is "next,2,1,previous" instead of "previous,1,2,next"???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How stupid!! Finally found the problem, the elements had a "float: right" so that caused the reverse order....

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried moving the ordering into a scope?

You could have a scope in your model like

```
scope :order_by, lambda { |o| { :order => o } }
```

And then write your paginate line as

```
@notes = @contact.notes.order_by("created_at ASC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping `order` in a scope instead of calling it directly (`@contect.notes.order("created_at ASC").paginate(....)`)?

Comment: Good point Dan. This is a leftover from my Rails 2.3 days. You're quite right. I guess it depends what version of Rails John is using.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was that the `:include => :notes` could confuse will_paginate. Have you tried to leave it out?

Comment: Unfortunately that makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
@notes = @contact.notes.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5, :order => "notes.created_at ASC")

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes,:order => "...." #remove this order option if you did
end

class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :order => "..." # remove this order option if you did
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You supplied `:order => "created_at ASC"` to the paginate method instead of the active object you want to have sorted in some way. I could not find the exact point in the `will_paginate` gem,
but I bet that the view helper method `will_paginate` checks order to see if it goes from left to right or from right to left.

The modified version of Simmo's answer incorporating Dan Seavers suggesion should be correct:

`@notes = @contact.notes.order("created_at ASC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)`